# Aligning Image & Media Body Centre Inside Bootstrap Media Object

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

this is my first post on stackoverflow so hope everything comes across smoothly.

I have 3 media objects that all consist of an image and some content. I am having trouble aligning the content central and the images to the left and right of the centre. I have attached a picture of the current result as well as a diagram of how i'd like the page to be laid out (see below).

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2GkL.png) 
[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uDWd.png)

here is my code;

```
<!-- Reviews start !-->
    <section id="reviews">
            <div class="media border p-3 center-stuff col">
                <img src="images/prof-1.jpg" class="rounded-circle media-img mt-2 align-self-center">
                <div class="media-body col-md-12 center-stuff">
                    <h4 class="mt-3">Stan Dutton <small><i>In Store Review on October 18, 2019</i></small></h4>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="mb-3">"Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!""Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!"</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p class="center-stuff">Customer Satisfaction %</p>
                    <div class="progress col-6 center-stuff mb-3">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:93%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media border p-3 mt-3">
                <div class="media-body col-md-12 center-stuff">
                    <h4 class="mt-3">Stan Dutton <small><i>In Store Review on October 18, 2019</i></small></h4>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="mb-3">"Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!""Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!"</p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p class="center-stuff">Customer Satisfaction %</p>
                    <div class="progress col-6 center-stuff mb-3">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:93%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Stan Dutton *In Store Review on October 18, 2019*

> "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!""Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable open till close, can't get enough!"

Customer Satisfaction %

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<section id="reviews">
            <div class="media border p-3 center-stuff col">
                <img
                    src="images/prof-1.jpg"
                    class="rounded-circle media-img mt-2 align-self-center"
                />
                <div class="media-body col-md-12 center-stuff">
                    <h4 class="mt-3">
                        Stan Dutton
                        <small
                            ><i>In Store Review on October 18, 2019</i></small
                        >
                    </h4>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable
                            open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point.
                            Free retro games consoles playable open till close,
                            can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games
                            consoles playable open till close, can't get
                            enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles
                            playable open till close, can't get enough!""Ale on
                            point. Free retro games consoles playable open till
                            close, can't get enough!"
                        </p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p class="center-stuff">Customer Satisfaction %</p>
                    <div class="progress col-6 center-stuff mb-3">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:93%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media border p-3 center-stuff col">
                <div class="media-body col-md-12 center-stuff">
                    <h4 class="mt-3">
                        Stan Dutton
                        <small
                            ><i>In Store Review on October 18, 2019</i></small
                        >
                    </h4>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable
                            open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point.
                            Free retro games consoles playable open till close,
                            can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games
                            consoles playable open till close, can't get
                            enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles
                            playable open till close, can't get enough!""Ale on
                            point. Free retro games consoles playable open till
                            close, can't get enough!"
                        </p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p class="center-stuff">Customer Satisfaction %</p>
                    <div class="progress col-6 center-stuff mb-3">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:93%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <img
                    src="images/prof-1.jpg"
                    class="rounded-circle media-img mt-2 align-self-center"
                />
            </div>
            <div class="media border p-3 center-stuff col">
                <img
                    src="images/prof-1.jpg"
                    class="rounded-circle media-img mt-2 align-self-center"
                />
                <div class="media-body col-md-12 center-stuff">
                    <h4 class="mt-3">
                        Stan Dutton
                        <small
                            ><i>In Store Review on October 18, 2019</i></small
                        >
                    </h4>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles playable
                            open till close, can't get enough!" "Ale on point.
                            Free retro games consoles playable open till close,
                            can't get enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games
                            consoles playable open till close, can't get
                            enough!" "Ale on point. Free retro games consoles
                            playable open till close, can't get enough!""Ale on
                            point. Free retro games consoles playable open till
                            close, can't get enough!"
                        </p>
                    </blockquote>
                    <p class="center-stuff">Customer Satisfaction %</p>
                    <div class="progress col-6 center-stuff mb-3">
                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width:93%"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</section>
```

Comment: fixed this with flex boxes and a lot more containers, thank you for your answer